# Unable to get property 'appendChild' of undefined or null reference in WCF Rest

Tags: c#, javascript, wcf-rest

I have Developed a WCF Rest  Service which returns dateTime.
When I Run the Service in IE, Service is breaking and giving exception stating that

> Unhandled exception at line 82, column 1840 in script block
>   0x800a138f - JavaScript run time error: Unable to get property 'appendChild' of undefined or null reference

Where as If I run the same service in Other Browsers like Chrome or Firefox the exception is not occurring at all.

Comment: according this link [http://reference.sitepoint.com/javascript/Node/appendChild#compatibilitysection](http://reference.sitepoint.com/javascript/Node/appendChild#compatibilitysection), appendChild is fully supported on IE (even on IE5....). Moreover, you possibly call this method on an undefined or null DOM element: the error might not be related to your web service.
You could try to indent your javascript properly, hit F12 on IE to open developer tools and debug your javascript.
Otherwise add the related code in the post please

Answer (score 0):

Also, to dovetail on the previous response, IE10 is quite strict, and I find that when debugging in F12, often the root of an 'undefined or null reference' error report is, in fact, not the reference itself, but something earlier in the DOM. So, when you open the F12 debugger and run it, be sure to watch 'locals' as you run through the script to be sure where the first breakdown is of a reference not being passed. You could have an issue with an unrelated feature that IE10 (or 11) no longer supports. In which case, there is an updated syntax and term for the functionality.